# размещение маркера на картинке

Tags: java, android

Есть картинка (план помещения). Нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе данных на этом плане выскакивал маркер, как-то выделял место и с аннотацией. Подскажите как это реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ну как вариант. Для каждого посадочного места рассчитать относительное расположение маркера для него на исходной картинке (в % от высоты и ширины картинки). Затем, когда нужно поставить маркер, брать размер изображения на экране и высчитывать положение маркера. После рисовать маркер с необходимыми данными в выбранном месте.